# How to multiply(*) without using multiply(*) JOLT

Tags: multiplication, jolt

Multiplying in JOLT. How to multiply without using multiply.

- 

Comment: Hi sanskar, yes there's no multiply function within the answer, but we can reproduce by using the function of division as you already have mentioned. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a5841306%20%5bjolt%5d%20multiply&searchOn=3) out for sample implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with simple mathematics.

For Example -

We want to multiply - 2 * 3 which  = 6

By using divide we do this like 2/ 1/3 is also = 6
that is 2 * 0.3333 = 6,

2 divide by 1 / 3 = 6